# Scraping Google public data

Tags: web-scraping

I'm interested in scraping this dataset from Google Public data:

https://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=gb66jodhlsaab_#!ctype=l&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=h&met_y=Capital_St&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=state&idim=state:AL:AK:AZ:AR:CO:CA:CT:DE:DC:FL:GA:HI:IL:ID:IN:KS:KY:LA:IA:ME:MD:MA:MI:MS:MO:MN:MT:NV:NH:NE:NJ:NM:NY:NC:ND:OK:OH:OR:PA:RI:SC:SD:TX:UT:TN:VT:WA:VA:WV:WI:WY&ifdim=state&hl=en_US&dl=en_US&ind=false

Is there a way to do it, given that when I click on the link of the bottom of the page, it's not obvious where the data are stored? (And Google Public data doesn't allow downloads?)

Comment: There's a link at the bottom of the page which leads to where the dataset came from. They've got data available in Excel so it might be what you are looking for. https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/policyinformation/index.cfm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a link at the bottom of the page which leads to where the dataset came from. They've got data available in Excel so it might be what you are looking for.

https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/policyinformation/index.cfm